# Katta Execution Error

Tags: lucene, katta

Hi I tried
**bin/katta search IndexName "Query"**

the above one is works fine and

**bin/katta search IndexName "Query" 100**
which is also works fine,

I write a program
ILuceneClient client = new LuceneClient();
client.count(....) //works fine

But the below one is throwing exception

**Hits hits = client.search(query,new String[] { _kattaIndexName });**

==================================================================================
11/03/22 07:43:36 WARN client.NodeInteraction:159 - Failed to interact with node hadoop5:20000. Trying with other node(s) [hadoop4:20000, hadoop1:20000] (id=6)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.sf.katta.client.NodeInteraction.run(NodeInteraction.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: Multithread shard search could not be executed:
    at net.sf.katta.lib.lucene.LuceneServer.search(LuceneServer.java:416)
    at net.sf.katta.lib.lucene.LuceneServer.search(LuceneServer.java:261)
    at net.sf.katta.lib.lucene.LuceneServer.search(LuceneServer.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:955)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)

## at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:953)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met with a similar problem when using eclipse in windows as a client. I found out that I have used a different version of lucence core as that on the katta cluster's lib. It seems that Hadoop IPC is very sensitive to versioning. So you should make sure that your eclipse has used the same version of lucene core as that your katta lib contains.